# Meaning and connotation of "_______ your heart out"

Tags: meaning, connotations

What does _____  your heart out mean? Does it carry a positive connotation or a negative one?

For example:

> work your heart out.

Does this mean that you like working, so you should do it to your heart's content, or does it mean you do a lot of what you don't like to do (work)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not trying hard enough, someone might say to you this common idiomatic phrase:

> Put your heart into it (what you are doing).

It means to put all of your effort, interest and concentration in order to meet your goal or complete your task.

> work your heart out

is similar in meaning:

> If you want to stay in shape, you need to **work your heart out** (exercise as best you can).

But putting other words in the blank the phrase may have a different meaning. The only one I can think of at the moment is:

> eat your heart out

Check [***eat one's heart out***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eat_one%27s_heart_out) and [***eat your heart out***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/eat-your-heart-out)

Comment: Also, it depends who's saying it, and with what intonation.  Said sarcastically, it means something like "Go ahead; be a fool and work yourself to death—I won't be that stupid!

Answer (score 0):

Work your heart out seems to me to be a polite version of work your ass off. Sing your heart out is a reference to emoting musically.
You can work your magic, work your fingers to the bone, or work like a dog.

Comment: If the OP doesn't know "work your heart out", I don't think telling them it's the same thing as "work your ass off" is going to be that helpful. You've given a lot of related phrases, but you don't explain what any of them mean exactly.